# How to customise view pager in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager in my app which i need customise. Answers in internet didn't provide a solution. Help me please. Thank you.

Here is my code.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pagerplan"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

```
public class Plans extends AppCompatActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerOperator mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    private String[] tabs = { "Full talktime", "Special recharge", "2G data" };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_plans);

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white)));
        actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#000000'>SELECT PLAN</font>"));
        actionBar.show();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
        upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagerplan);
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerOperator(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);




        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
           actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
           // actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.adipoli));

        }

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_plans, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What you need to customize? Tell us in brief!

Comment: I need to change tabs background color, text color and font

Comment: Customization of  `ViewPager` is not related with change of Tabs background color, text color and font.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry for that.. but i actually wanted to customise tabs

Comment: This is old way, Search for Sliding tab layout.

Comment: But how do you want to customize ?

Comment: @Harry..thanku for your suggestion

Comment: @ Piyush..i need to change colors of tab

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your xml code like below.

**view_pager.xml**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="android:background">@color/btn_background</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabText</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTabText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```